# Proposal to rename [desexing] tag to [neutering]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

For UK/US users [desexing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desexing) is not a tag most would think to look for when refering to spay, neuter, castration, etc. In fact "desexing" is a term that I (a vet) have never heard used by any veterinary professional. It does seem that it is primarily an Australian term, but I have not practiced there so it might be commonly used by Australian vets.

Animals are not really "de-sexed" - they still have some sexual organs, they are still male and female. I have been told I take things too literally sometimes, but this particular term does not describe the procedure very accurately.

Currently [desexing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desexing) has two synonyms - [neutering](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutering) and [spay](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spay).

This is a proposal to make [neutering](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutering) the primary tag, and [desexing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desexing) a synonym of that. I think neutering is a far more universally-used term than desexing, and can be applied to both males and females.

On searching, this has come up years ago, but I think warrants a fresh look:

- [Questions about desexing](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/questions-about-desexing)
- [Request mod-level synonyms be created for [spaying] / [neutering] / [fixing]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/698/request-mod-level-synonyms-be-created-for-spaying-neutering-fixing)

Comment: I agree with this, I've only ever seen the term de-sexing online - never hear it in person.

Comment: For those who may not be aware both 'Harry V' and 'Rebecca RVT' are Veterinary professionals.

Comment: Agreed.  De-sexing also sounds eye-wateringly painful.

Comment: Would you plan to make [tag:spay] become a synonym of [tag:neutering] as well? In the Meta's you linked to it sounded like they had some community support.

Comment: @Henders Yes, that is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 4):

The master tag is now [neutering](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutering), with the synonyms [desexing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desexing) and [spaying](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaying).

You will note the tags on the questions prior to this synonym reversal are still tagged with  [desexing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desexing), however on search results the [neutering](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutering) will show up.

Another question should be, if we need to retag them.

Also, our tag wikis are now empty.

Answer (score 1):

I was redirected here from this [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313298/tag-synonym-disappeared-after-swapping-tag-master-with-synonym) post.

I can understand the need to come up with a term other than *desexing*, if it is inappropriate; but I can't understand the reasoning behind making *neuter* a synonym of *spay* (or vice versa).

Despite lexicographical evidence, I have always known *neuter* to be a specifically male term and *spay* to be a specifically female term. Where I live, I've never heard anybody refer to spaying a male animal or neutering a female animal.

It would be kind of like saying that *man* is a synonym of *woman* (or vice versa) rather than saying that each is a synonym of *human*.

I would suggest picking something like *sterilization* as a better word for *desexing*. And then making both *neuter* and *spay* synonyms of *that* instead.

But whatever word you pick as an "umbrella" term, I don't think that either *neuter* or *spay* should be synonymous with the other.

---

**Update**: Spurred by comments, it appears that my "common knowledge" of the two words has been incorrect.

I was raised to specifically associate one gender with each word. (And this was reinforced by vets I've dealt with here in Canada.) But the dictionary has something different to say.

Merriam-Webster specifically states that [**spay**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spay) is associated with female animals:

> : to remove the ovaries and uterus of (a female animal)

However, its definition of *neuter* "redirects" to [**castrate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/castrate), which in turn refers to both sexes:

**2 a** : to deprive of the testes : GELD
**b** : to deprive of the ovaries (see OVARY 1) : SPAY

(More interestingly, I've never heard of the word *castrate* applied to females before either.)

Given this, it does indeed seem to make sense that **neuter** should be the main word, and **spay** a synonym of it.

---

But it still sounds "off" to me—perhaps the words have different regional uses.

Here is some copy from the website of [Parkland Veterinary Clinic](http://parklandvet.net/veterinary-services/spay-and-neuter/):

> Specifically, spaying is the surgical removal of the uterus and ovaries and, on the other hand, neutering is the surgical removal of your pets’ testicles.

This tells me that even if usage has changed over the past forty years or so (I'm not sure if it actually has), some people still do make this distinction between the different words.

Comment: welcome to our site :) I take it you're an English language expert? high rep in such a short time on English.se

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't know if I'd call myself an "expert," but I'm an editor who like working with words. ;)

Comment: well if you have pets, feel free to ask or answer questions and post pics in our chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box

Comment: This is incorrect. You dig a garden with a *spade*. An animal is *spayed* (or *speyed* to some). [Neutering (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutering) can refer to both male and female animals.

Comment: @HarryV. You are quite correct. (And I am embarrassed about not catching my unconscious typo.)  I have updated my answer.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I have made some further edits to smooth out this inconsistency.